# blob not storing any value for any reason

Tags: javascript, blob, webrtc, jsfiddle

Recording a video with webRTC I have no data, and after debugging I just realized that there's no content in the Blob variable (that must store the video).

According to the code I pasted on my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DevStarlight/dmktf3rv/5/), line 136 should contain something like:

```
Blob {type: "audio/wav", size: 360492, slice: function}size: 360492type: "audio/wav"
```

But its value is `undefined`.

Could anybody tell me what am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call stopRecording and get the blob within the callback. The callback will also be passed a data URL.

```
if (!isFirefox) {
    recordAudio.stopRecording(function(dataURL){
        var bloba = recordAudio.getBlob();
        console.log("Audio Blob",bloba);
    });
    fileType = 'audio';
    fileName = 'test.wav';
} else {
    recordAudio.stopRecording(function(dataURL){
        var bloba = recordAudio.getBlob();
        console.log("Audio Blob",bloba);
    });
    fileType = 'video';
    fileName = 'test.webm';
}
if (!isFirefox) {
    recordVideo.stopRecording(function(dataURL){
        var blobv = recordVideo.getBlob();
        console.log("Video Blob",blobv);
    });
    fileType = 'video';
    fileName = 'test.webm';
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tkybrzqy/)